# Como construir um diferenciável para uma classe Generic?

Tags: java, genéricos

Como seria possível construir um construtor diferenciado para classes que estendem uma classe genérica?

Por exemplo, para a situação abaixo, eu gostaria de criar um construtor de Generic conseguisse realizar a instrução **entity = E.class;**, mas por enquanto não consegui. De forma que ele pudesse ser invocado no construtor da classe ItemManager.

Como poderíamos fazer isso?

```
public class Generic<E> {
    private Class<E> entity;

    public void setEntity(Class<E> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Generic() {
        entity = E.class;
    }
}

class ItemManager extends Generic<Item> {
    public ItemManager() {
        super(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: `entity` deve referenciar um objeto, ele não pode referenciar um class. Diga-nos qual é a intenção dessa aplicação para tentarmos encontrar uma solução. Na verdade eu também não entendi essa linha: `private Class<E> entity;` pode fazer isso? Qual é o resultado?

Comment: Sim, aquela linha é possível. E exceto o construtor *public Generic*, tudo funciona. Mas, eu preciso em cada construtor fazer um setEntity, ou seja, dentro do construtor de ItemManager, ao invés de apenas chamar super, estou precisando fazer um setEntity(Entity.class) por exemplo. Mas essa Entity é justamente o parâmetro E que eu estou passando para o Generic, portanto eu queria automatizar isso. O motivo para isso é para fazer uma classe genérica para operar sobre o banco de dados com diversos métodos automatizados.

Answer (score 3):

A intenção do seu código está confusa. Mas se entendi bem você quer armazenar o tipo da entidade e não uma instância dela.

Então basta fazer seu construtor assim:

```
public abstract class Generic<E> {
    private Class<E> entityClass;

    public Generic() {
        this.entityClass = (Class<E>) 
            ((ParameterizedType) getClass().getGenericSuperclass())
                .getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }
}
```

Nota: mudei o atributo `entity` para `entityClass` para deixar mais claro que não é uma **entidade** que está sendo armazenada mas o **tipo (classe)** da entidade.

---

No entanto, se quiser receber a instância da entidade mesmo, o código fica assim:

```
public abstract class Generic<E> {
    private E entity;

    public void setEntity(E entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

Comment: É bom notar que esta magia não estende ao possibilidade de executar, por exemplo, `new Generic<Item>()`. Pois `Generic` faria mais sentido como um class `abstract`.

Comment: @DanGetz Muito bom! `abstract` adicionado.

Answer (score 2):

Pode ser mais simples utilizar `Item.class` onde é possível, e passá-lo ao construtor de `Generic`:

```
public class Generic<E> {
    ...
    public Generic(Class<E> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}

class ItemManager extends Generic<Item> {
    public ItemManager() {
        super(Item.class);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

***Exemplo:***

**Class** `Generic`

```
public class Generic <E> {
    private Class<E> entity;

    public void setEntity(Class<E> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }

    public Generic(Class<E> entity) {
        this.entity = entity;
    }
}
```

**Class** `ItemManager`

```
public class ItemManager<E> extends Generic<E> {
    public ItemManager(Class<E> entity){        
        super(entity);
    }
}
```

**Instanciando**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    ItemManager<Item> itemManager = new ItemManager<>(Item.class); 
    System.out.print(itemManager.getEntity());

}
```